# Where do the locals in Rhodes do their groceries?

Tags: shopping, greece

August last year I had a holiday in Trianta, on the island named Rhodes. It wasn't a very touristic area, but close to most of the attractions and sights (with a taxi it took around 30 min to reach Rhodes city).

Close to our hotel, there was a small grocery store that had most of the basic supplies you'd want during your stay, like coffee, water, bread etc.

The prices however were much higher than I expected it to be. Almost 2 times as high as you'd pay in the Netherlands. In other shops we've encountered the same, or at least similar prices.

I'm wondering, is this usual for greek people? Or do they go to different places to do their groceries?

Comment: While I don't have any experience of Greek islands, the high prices don't sound unusual for a remote island with small population.  Keep in mind that, while Turkey is quite close by, most food is probably coming from the EU, probably on trucks loaded on ferries that make several stops and go several hundred miles/km to reach the island.

Comment: Keep in mind that Dutch supermarket prices are about the lowest in the world, which influences your frame of reference.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! I wasn't aware of shipment and / or pricing in NL.

Comment: If you could visit a supermarket (probably in the city of Rhodes) you would find considerably lower prices. But isn't this happening everywhere in the world? I find it normal for small local shops to have higher prices than supermarkets.

Comment: @Glorfindel Says who?

Comment: Generally the prices in Greece are very high in comparison with other countries in the world due to very big taxes in basic goods

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Residents of towns and small cities in Greece usually shop from:

- Supermarkets
- Local markets
- Farmer's markets (*Λαϊκή* in greek)
- Local stores, such as fishmongers, butchers etc.

Small grocery stores are usually used only for emergencies, fixed priced goods (prepaid cards and tobacco products mostly) and food to be consumed on the go (soft drinks, ice cream, etc.). They are far more expensive than supermarkets, but usually conveniently placed and open for more hours.

Now, compared to the Netherlands, in my experience, you will find very large price differences in some products even in large supermarkets in Athens. Some cheaper (vegetables, fruit), some more expensive (dairy products).

Comment: Thanks for actually answering the question! (While I did appreciate the comments too, as they explained my bias!)